# Get the content of childNodes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML structure like below. I need to get the header content and description content.

```
<div id="results">
    <div class="ui list">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="content">
                <a class="header" onclick=" toMaker(event, 967)">Mahachai Holding</a>
                <div class="description">Lat Phrao, Bangkok, 10230</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have used following code

```
$('#results > .ui.list')[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML
```

to get the string like

`"<a class="header" onclick=" toMaker(event, 967)">MahachaiHolding</a><div class="description">Lat Phrao, Bangkok, 10230</div>"`

But now I am confused about how to get header name and description name?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/text/ ?

Comment: Would go with `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the `.html()` of the `.header` and `.description`

```js
const $content = $("#results .ui.list .item .content");
console.log($content.find(".header").html());
console.log($content.find(".description").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results">
  <div class="ui list">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content">
        <a class="header" onclick=" toMaker(event, 967)">Mahachai Holding</a>
        <div class="description">Lat Phrao, Bangkok, 10230</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#results > .ui.list')[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML

$('#results > .ui.list').find('.header') //will get you header element
$('#results > .ui.list').find('.description') //will get you description element
```

is this what you mean?

https://api.jquery.com/find/

refrence url

Comment: I almost forgot about "find". its easier

Comment: then you can access all relevent stuff from this element Im not sure what you need but for example .text() will get you inner text

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

> The output will give only the text of the element not the inner html

```js
/// Get the header text 
console.log($('#results .ui.list a.header').text());

/// Get the description text 
console.log($('#results .ui.list div.description').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="results">
  <div class="ui list">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content">
        <a class="header" onclick=" toMaker(event, 967)">Mahachai Holding</a>
        <div class="description">Lat Phrao, Bangkok, 10230</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log($(".content").text())
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="results">
        <div class="ui list">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="content">
                    <a class="header" onclick=" toMaker(event, 967)">Mahachai Holding</a>
                    <div class="description">Lat Phrao, Bangkok, 10230</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```